# What's a safe way to let a web user input code representing a formula?

Tags: python, input, frontend

I want to let users input a custom formula through a web app, so that I can calculate and return a graphical shape and show it on the front-end. This means their formula should be executed on the server. This is dangerous, of course!

What's a good practice to achieve this while making sure that I am not opening the door for all sorts of malicious activities?

Here are some extra conditions that I can impose:

- The variables are predefined, e.g., `var.x, var.y, var.z`. Both the number of variables and their names are fixed.
- Users should be able to add a constant value to their formula.
- The formula should be eventually executed using Python.

What I have in mind is to let them input a string (in Python) that has their implementation of their formula. To minimize the danger, I can make sure each component of the formula has one of the fixed variables, and also, set a fixed length to the given string! This may be enough, but it does not sound very smart!

Any better suggestion?

Comment: Couldn't you make it an interface, into which they cannot type, but rather build the formula from the predefined components (variables and operators). They only typing would be number values into input fields for variables.

Comment: @Eleshar, thanks for the suggestion. Well, these formulas could get really complicated, and I don't want to force them to simplify their formulas to fit in a certain interface.